# Extra internal hard disk creation

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, disk-management

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and I also want an extra storage in another inbuilt hard disc by partition so that I can store files in it separately . I did create create a partition and named it but it shows a "Mount/Unmount" option by its side . However I want it to be permanently present rather than mounting and un-mounting it 'cause sometimes the system does not allows me to mount it saying I do not have the access or something .

P.S : I have windows installed as dual boot and I dont want that to be disturbed or interfered also by my partitioning

[image]

Comment: What format is Personal partition? Mount parameters with fstab vary by format. And if Linux format you have to give yourself ownership & permissions. NTFS only gets default ownership & permissions from mount in fstab or automount when clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the volume in the /etc/fstab,
see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions